# How to place several plots side by side?

Tags: plotting

I want to place multiple `MatrixPlot` results side by side. Here's the example code:

```
data1 = ( {
   {1, 2},
   {3, 4}
  } ); 
data2 = ( {
       {5, 6},
       {7, 8}
      } );
fig1 = MatrixPlot[data1, PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, {0, 0.5}]];
fig2 = MatrixPlot[data2, PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, {1, 0.5}]];
GraphicsRow[{fig1, fig2}]
```

I get the following result:

[image]

But what I want is the following:

[image]

What should I do to get the second figure, that I have currently generated using another tool?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
data1 = ({{1, 2}, {3, 4}}); data2 = ({{5, 6}, {7, 8}});
fig1 = MatrixPlot[data1, PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, {0, 0.5}], 
   FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {Automatic, None}}
   , ImageSize -> 400
   ];
fig2 = MatrixPlot[data2, PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, {1, 0.5}]
   , FrameTicks -> {{None, Automatic}, {Automatic, None}}
   , ImageSize -> 400
   ];
GraphicsRow[{fig1, fig2}, Spacings -> {5, 0}]
```

[image]

Comment: Can there be no gap at all in the middle? Okay, It seems I can set Spacing to -10 to get no gap.